# Getting TypeError after passing an Object via props in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've a vue3 page & vue3 component. The vue3 Page, is getting data via a composable accessing Firebase/Firestore and passing the Object as a prop to a component on the vue3 page. However, when attempting accessing the properties of the prop in the script setup section, I get a TypeError.

Could you help me understand this better and what I am doing wrong?

useProfiles:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { db } from "/@src/composable/useFirebase"

import {
    doc,
    onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export const profile = ref({});

export const getProfile = async (id) => {
  const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "profiles", id), { includeMetadataChanges: true }, (doc) => {
    profile.value = doc.data()
    profile.value['id'] = doc.id
  });
};
```

Vue Page:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { getProfile, profile } from '/@src/composable/useProfiles'

const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('id')

onMounted(async () => { 
  getProfile(params);
})

</script>

<template>
  <div class="page-content-inner">
    <Core-MyProfile v-if="!params" />
    <Core-UserProfile v-if="params" :profile="profile"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Vue Component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  profile: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
})

const sellPoints = props.profile.tribute.sell.current
const timePoints = props.profile.tribute.time.current
const usePoints = props.profile.tribute.use.current

const totalPoints = computed(
  () => sellPoints+timePoints+usePoints
);

</script>
```

Errors:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "profile". Expected Object, got Undefined  
  at <CoreUserProfile key=1 profile=undefined > 
  at <Index onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > key="/profile?id=FC9gNTJ7D2hMaBcna9ILTGyxB3E2" > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="fade-fast" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <HomeLayout> 
  at <Profile onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="fade-slow" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

---

runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <CoreUserProfile key=1 profile=undefined > 
  at <Index onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > key="/profile?id=0TCIgQZxy5YJqyXNMZQqkBQhZv13" > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="fade-fast" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <HomeLayout> 
  at <Profile onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="fade-slow" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

---

Core-UserProfile.vue:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tribute')
    at setup (Core-UserProfile.vue:12:34)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7165:29)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7120:11)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5473:13)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5448:17)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5038:21)
    at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5234:13)
    at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5143:17)
    at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5115:13)
```

Comment: There's no ReferenceError in error log that you posted. It's unknown what an error refers to, in case there's one.

Comment: Apologies, I've adjusted the code and the error changes, I'll update the headline, thanks for highlighting this :)

Comment: You didn't show useProfiles. The error means what it says. You rely on `profile` to exist at the moment when the comp Core-UserProfile renders, but it doesn't exist

Comment: Updated accordingly and added code of useProfiles

Comment: This doesn't explain how `profile` could be undefined. It's {} initially. Consider using initial value that could allow to distinguish uninitialized value like `profile = ref({})`, then you can do `v-if="params && profile"`

Comment: That I did now, so it's ``` profile = ref({ personal: { names: {} } }) ``` and I can access "first", however, as mentioned in a comment on the answer below, I'll be using interfaces / type declarations going forward (as soon as I figured out how to properly ) so it'll be somehting like ``` profile = ref<Profile>({}) ``` - something like that. Still working on it.

Comment: Are you able to set a default value to the profile propTypes? (specifically where you "defineProps") This way you could allow for undefined and return an different value rather then throwing errors.